# How to catch event on a parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to ask:

- How to make the group displays OVER the divs a and b?
- I want to catch event mousedown on group even if a user click on a div a or b.

Basically the group should visually cover the two other divs, so when I click inside the are covered by the group, only group div should detect mousedown.

Notes: I cannot change HTML structure.

```js
document.getElementById('group').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert('click on: ' + event.target.id);
});
```

```css
#group {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 0;
}

#b {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="group">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking. If you click on A or B, your event bubbles up (all JavaScript events bubble up). You're saying if you have other elements inside the group you want to detect the click on those as well? Have you tried it and it doesn't work?

Comment: explain your problem a little more

Comment: what if you discard any event click if id is 'group' ?
`if(event.target.id !== 'group') { alert('click on: ' + event.target.id) }`

Comment: Unclear Question :(

Comment: I need to, when i click in the yellow area (the group) always catch the group event. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use opacity 0 for the children.
2. Use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`.

With this config children are actually above `groups`, but are not visible and events are caught by `groups` elem, not children.

```js
document.getElementById('group').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert('click on: ' + event.currentTarget.id);
});
```

```css
#group {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#a {
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0
}

#b {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="group">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
</div>
```